# Rails 4.2 and postgres - cannot update an attribute, possible reasons?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have stumbled upon a strange behavior with updates of a certain record. I have a sample project in which I have models Restaurant, Hotel, RestaurantRating, HotelRating...they are almost indeticall, just copy paste and different names in attributes. I have a rake task, which I use to populate my database. In this rake task, I am also creating ratings to hotels and restaurants and in an after_save callback, I am recounting an average rating for a each attribute for hotels and restaurants. The same code works for hotels, but doesn't work for Restaurant since the update to Rails 4.2.1 (it worked in 4.0.12).

The update looks like this:

```
def update_restaurants_avg_rating
  DA::RESTAURANT_RATING_TYPES.each do |type|
    result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT AVG(restaurant_ratings.#{type}) FROM restaurant_ratings WHERE restaurant_ratings.restaurant_id = #{self.restaurant_id}").values[0][0].to_f
    Restaurant.where(id: self.restaurant_id).first.update_attribute("avg_rating_#{type}", result)
  end
end
```

No update is seen in log (I can see update command for Hotels but not for restaurants), the value is not persisted into Postgres. It looks like something entirely different is in play which causes this behavior.
Does anybody has any idea, what could be the reason for such a behavior? Btw I have tested many possible commands, avoided usage of Base.connection etc.

Just for completion, update code for Hotels:

```
def update_hotels_avg_rating
  DA::HOTEL_RATING_TYPES.each do |type|
    result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT AVG(hotel_ratings.#{type}) FROM hotel_ratings WHERE hotel_ratings.hotel_id = #{self.hotel_id}").values[0][0].to_f
    Hotel.where(id: self.hotel_id).first.update_attribute("avg_rating_#{type}", result)      
  end
end
```

**EDIT:** I have been digging deeper and found out, that the problem is probably because when updating a Restaurant, the attribute_names in an active record are empty, so no column is updated but still...I don't know why. At this line:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d937a1175f10586b892842348c1d6ecaa47aad2e/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L528
attribute_names are empty for restaurant but contains updated attribute + "updated_at" for Hotel.

But I am not sure which part of rails is responsible for it - guess some part of rails is not recognizing updated attribute.

Comment: Have you tried to update Restaurant table from rails console?

Comment: Tried it now with a following command: Restaurant.where(id: 1).first.update_attribute("avg_rating_service", 1) , and it works, but the code above for some reason does not.

Comment: I'm guessing that it's different environment databases, make sure your rake task and code in rails console are interacting with the same database

Comment: I am sure that it is the same database, because the rake task contains the code for creation of all the data (Hotels, Restaurant and their ratings) and Hotels are created without any problems but Restaurants are not - it's all one rake task and the code is almost copy paste between hotels and restaurants. And I am using phpPgAdmin to view the results - update in console resulted in an update in my Postgres DB and so did the results of the rake task.

Comment: I meant the different databases like test, development and production. When you're just typing 'rails console' you entering into development database. You have to find out which database you're on when launching rake task.

Comment: Test and development databases are the same, I have run rake task in development environment and the console was also run in development environment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88316/discussion-between-megas-and-giron).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found the source of the problem (but not the error) - migration files were different for Hotels and Restaurants. Hotels used migration using method **change** with calling t.integer etc. , on the other hand, Restaurants used methods **up** and **down** with using add_column. When I changed migration to use change method with t.integer, it worked.

Funny thing, both migrations created exactly the same tables before and after the change (checked in phppgadmin). I guess this will stay a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

So you see an UPDATE query, but no change happens to the record?

Check for a ROLLBACK -- if I had to guess I'd say that there is a validation failing.

Perhaps try update_attributes!, which will throw an exception if the record is invalid.

Comment: Hi - No, i Can't see and update query, I can see it only for Hotels but not for Restaurants. Btw those records are invalid and it is on purpose, so the update_attribute is used to avoid validation,